# How to use a Logical OR Operator in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

Currently I am using this function to copy/paste rows from the Mastersheet that have a cell that consists of the value "Beleggersprofielen" to my worksheet.

```
=FILTER( Recherche!B4:N , Recherche!O4:O1002 = "Beleggersprofielen")
```

But I would like this function to also check whether another column consists of another value. Because than it that specific row may also be copy/pasted.

I tried the following:

```
=FILTER( Recherche!B4:N , Recherche!O4:O1002 = "Beleggersprofielen"| Recherche!C4:C1002 = "11 - 20" )
```

But this gives error: **Parse Error**

How can I use a Logical OR Operator in my function?

**EDIT**

I tried the following

```
=FILTER( Recherche!B4:O,(Recherche!M4:M1002="Beleggersprofielen")+(Recherche!E4:E1002="11 - 20")+(Recherche!E4:E1002="21 - 50")+(Recherche!E4:E1002="51 - 100")+(Recherche!E4:E1002="101 - 250")+(Recherche!E4:E1002="251 - 500")+(Recherche!E4:E1002="501 - 1000"))
```

This results in: success.

Comment: I will, delete the last edit, thank you for the heads up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Formula

Instead of

```
=FILTER( Recherche!B4:N , 
Recherche!O4:O1002 = "Beleggersprofielen"| Recherche!C4:C1002 = "11 - 20" )
```

Note: Added a breakline for readability. This haven't affect how the formula works.

Try

```
=FILTER( Recherche!B4:N1002,
(Recherche!O4:O1002="Beleggersprofielen")+(Recherche!C4:C1002="11 - 20"))
```

Note: FILTER require that the arguments be of the same size

## Explanation

- For scalar formulas use [OR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093306?hl=en), for arrays use + or [ADD](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093590?hl=en).
- The pipe character could be used as OR operator in functions that allow regular expressions, FILTER isn't one of them.
- OR function allows scalar values, not arrays.
- In Google Sheets, booleans are coerced as 1 (TRUE) and 0 (FALSE) in some functions. Other may require the use of [N](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093357?hl=en).
- Due to the precedence rules, enclose each comparison between parenthesis.

Comment: That worked, thanks!  Pls see EDIT 1

Comment: Add `+(Re‌​cherche!E4:E1002=string)` for each string where string is "21-50", etc.

Comment: So in my case that would mean 4 or 5 times such an addition?

Comment: That is one alternative. There are many others.

Comment: Would you be so kind to look at my application as a response to your 'String' answer ? (EDIT)

Comment: I updated my answer to edit the first argument of FILTER and to add a note.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47877/discussion-between-ruben-and-mieer-darwesh).